# CloudFoundry error when using cf push: Error refreshing auth token. auth request failed: Invalid auth token: Invalid refresh token (expired)

Tags: ibm-cloud, cloud-foundry

I am using the CloudFoundry CLI, and I get the following error when doing a `cf push`:

> Error refreshing auth token. auth request failed: Invalid auth token:
>   Invalid refresh token (expired)

I had been using `cf push` successfully and then it stopped working with the error above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Once I logged in again using

```
cf login -u ...
```

I was able to conduct the `cf push` successfully.

Comment: It seems like the answer actually does answer the question as stated. What is not clear is why a new login was required. Answering this requires more details about the original app and the context in which it is being pushed.